# Python 3.9.12: f-string error - SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder, f-string

I am using Spyder with Python 3.9.12

Here is the code I have inside Spyder:

```
user_input = (input('Please enter a number between 1 and 12:>>' ))

while (not user_input.isdigit()) or (int(user_input) < 1 or int(user_input) > 12):
    print('Must be an integer between 1 and 12')
    user_input = input('Please make a selection:>> ')
user_input = int(user_input)
print('============================')
print()
print(f"This is the "{user_input}" times table")
print()
for i in range(1,13):
    print(f""{i}" x "{user_input}" = "{i=user_input}"")
```

Error output from Spyder:

```
runfile('/Users/user/spyder-files/For-Loops.py', wdir='/Users/user/spyder-files')
  File "<unknown>", line 49
    print(f""This is the "{user_input}" times table"")
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried using single quotes but get the same error message:

```
user_input = (input('Please enter a number between 1 and 12:>>' ))

while (not user_input.isdigit()) or (int(user_input) < 1 or int(user_input) > 12):
    print('Must be an integer between 1 and 12')
    user_input = input('Please make a selection:>> ')
user_input = int(user_input)
print('============================')
print()
print(f'This is the '{user_input}' times table')
print()
for i in range(1,13):
    print(f''{i}' x '{user_input}' = '{i=user_input}'')
```

Same error:

```
runfile('/Users/user/spyder-files/For-Loops.py', wdir='/Users/user/spyder-files')
  File "<unknown>", line 49
    print(f'This is the '{user_input}' times table')
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: You are allowed to mix single and double quotes to get what you want. Did you mean: `print(f'This is the "{user_input}" times table')`?

Comment: I changed the code to single quotes as you suggested, but now have a different error message:  **runfile('/Users/user/spyder-files/For-Loops.py', wdir='/Users/user/spyder-files')
  File "<unknown>", line 52
    print(f'"{i}" x "{user_input}" = "{i=user_input}"')
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: f-string: expecting '}'**

Comment: Yes, that's right - I found that one as well. Please be patient whilst Matthias fixes their answer.

Comment: Updated code: user_input = (input('Please enter a number between 1 and 12:>>' ))

while (not user_input.isdigit()) or (int(user_input) < 1 or int(user_input) > 12):
    print('Must be an integer between 1 and 12')
    user_input = input('Please make a selection:>> ')
user_input = int(user_input)
print('============================')
print()
print(f'This is the "{user_input}" times table')
print()
for i in range(1,13):
    print(f'"{i}" x "{user_input}" = "{i=user_input}"')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used double quotes in `f""{i}" x "{user_input}" = "{i=user_input}""`. Now the string starts at the first double quote and ends at the second. The following text now leads to a `SyntaxError`.

You could use triple quotes to define the string. The fourth is now part of the strings content.

```
f""""{i}" x "{user_input}" = "{i*user_input}""""
```

Or use different quotes

```
f'"{i}" x "{user_input}" = "{i=user_input}"'
```

Comment: or single quotes.

Comment: I was just editing this. :)

Comment: (Although the version with triple quotes is not quite right)

Comment: Right. I've just seen that. Will edit it. I had an `OutOfCoffeeError`.

Comment: Also the OP has made a syntax error: They meant: `print(f""""{i}" x "{user_input}" = "{i*user_input}" """)`

Comment: I've just had two of my mistakes pointed out to me - and still had upvotes, so please try your code out and fix the mistakes.

Comment: So this worked! Thanks! >>> print(f""""{i}" x "{user_input}" = "{i*user_input}" """)

Comment: Better to use: `print(f'"{i}" x "{user_input}" = "{i*user_input}"')`

Comment: It is also possible to escape quotes with a backslash . Like `print(f"\"{i}\" x \"{user_input}\" = \"{i*user_input}\"")`